# Chef. Can i override library method in wrapper-cookbook?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Example:
a - community cookbook,
b - wrapper cookbook

a/libraries/default.rb:

```
module Path
  def path
    '/var/'
  end

  def other_method; end
  ...
end
```

This module included in a-cookbook resource.
a/resources/default.rb:

```
include Path
...
a = path
b = other_method
...
```

I want to override path method in wrapper cookbook with:

b/libraries/default.rb:

```
module Path
  def path
    '/usr/'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, code in `libraries/` is just run as-is so all the normal Ruby rules about monkey patching apply.

Comment: Thank you. Found a bug in community cookbook - method that i want to override simply not called, it deceived me.